# configure list users for service provider WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2

I have installed Wso2 api manager and am trying to set up authentication and authorization via Api manager. I can't figure out how to configure certain users who will be able to login through the app. Currently, all users who are in user story are allowed to login. I need to restrict the ability to login to the app for a certain range of users. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding roles to the particular users. Refer to this doc https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/managing-users-and-roles/managing-user-roles/#managing-user-roles

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the roles and permissions according to your use case:

1. Create a role (eg: `testRole`) and assign required permissions except for the login permission(`Admin Permissions > Login`) to that role [1].
2. Create a new user(eg: `testUser`) and assign the `testRole` to that user[2].

Now the `testUser` that you have created has no login permissions to the app.

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/managing-users-and-roles/managing-user-roles/#create-user-roles

[2] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/managing-users-and-roles/managing-users/#adding-a-new-user